# Как сделать авторизацию на dle и на самопис. cms

Tags: php, авторизация

Подскажите как сделать авторизацию на своем cms и dle.

Пробовал прописывать в сессию

Пароль от сайта dle и id

```
$_SESSION['dle_user_id'] = $result;
$_SESSION['dle_password'] = md5($pass);
```

Не работает.
Моя cms в корне. DLE в папке `site.ru/dle`

---

Расковырял плагин авторизации dle 9.8 с ppbb

Так вот тоже не работает...

```
$auth = array('login'=>'test', pass=>md5('test'), 'email'=>'lol@lol.ru')

$time = time();

$_TIME = $time + (86400 * 60);

$result = $db->query('insert into `dle_users` set `email`=?s, `password`=?s, `name`=?s, `user_group`=4, `reg_date`=?s, `lastdate`=?s', $auth['email'], md5($auth['pass']), $auth['login'], $time, $time);

if($result) {
    $id = $db->insertId();
    $this->set_cookie( "dle_user_id", $id, 365 );
    $this->set_cookie( "dle_password", md5($auth['pass']), 365 );
    session_name();
    session_id();
    @session_register( 'dle_user_id' );
    @session_register( 'dle_password' );
    @session_register( 'member_lasttime' );
    $_SESSION['dle_user_id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['dle_password'] = md5($auth['pass']);
    $_SESSION['member_lasttime'] = $time;
    $_SESSION['dle_log'] = 0;
    $db->query( "UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY dle_users set lastdate=?s, logged_ip=?s WHERE user_id=?s", $_TIME, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $id );
    return true;
} else
    return false;
```

---

```
public function set_cookie($name, $value, $expires) {

    if( $expires )
        $expires = time() + ($expires * 86400);
    else
        $expires = FALSE;

    if( PHP_VERSION < 5.2 )
        setcookie( $name, $value, $expires, "/", DOMAIN . "; HttpOnly" );
    else
        setcookie( $name, $value, $expires, "/", DOMAIN, NULL, TRUE );

}
```